# Date function in JS, comparing with a set date not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have to pretty much validate and check if the user is underage in ASP. So anyone under the age of 01/07/1998 is underage. I have 3 dropdown lists to select date, month and year. Im using JS. I try using concat and split but they dont work. Can anyone help with this?

```
function ValidateDate() {
    var dDay = document.getElementById('DateList');
    var dMonth = document.getElementById('MonthList');
    var dYear = document.getElementById('YearList');

    var day = dDay.selectedIndex;
    var month = dMonth.selectedIndex;
    var year = dYear.selectedIndex;

    var firstValue = year + month  + day;

    var setyear = "1998";
    var setmonth = "06";
    var setdate = "01";
    var secondValue = setyear + setmonth + setdate;

    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setFullYear(firstValue[0], (firstValue[1] - 1), firstValue[2]);

    var secondDate = new Date();
    secondDate.setFullYear(secondValue[0], (secondValue[1] - 1), secondValue[2]);

    if (firstDate > secondDate) {
        alert("Pass");
    }
    else {
        alert("Fail");
    }

}

 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorDate" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage=" You are underage" CssClass="error" Display="Dynamic" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateDate" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your day, month and year variables are reading the index of the drop-downs and not their values.

For instance, you need to use:

```
var day = dDay.value,
month = dMonth.value,
year = dYear.value;
```

And then create date object as

```
var firstDate = new Date(year, month, day);
```

-Dipen